# formatting pandas dataframes for OLS regression in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-analysis, statsmodels

For an econometric analysis, I am attempting to run a regression on some education, health and income data taken from Brazil's central bank and a government research agency. Python, pandas, statsmodels and matplotlib are the external libraries I am using most for this project.

The format of the data is in multiple tables with each years for rows and cities/states for columns (some files have city data and some have state data).

Example of pandas dataframe on income by city and year:

```
1200302  1200328  ...   1720937  1720978  1721000  1721109  1721208  \
1970     0.31      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN      NaN     0.20     0.28   
1980     0.39      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN      NaN     0.45     0.57   
1991     0.44      NaN  ...       NaN      NaN     1.45     0.65     0.46
```

(Each number at the top is a city code - many cities have identical names.

For state data, there are 20-30 years measured for each state, whereas for cities this data is only available for 3-4 years, when the national census is carried out.)

I would like to compare indicators for education, health and income. All indicators have been selected and the datasets are imported into pandas dataframes and have been very minimally cleaned.

**How can I find R values for an OLS or FE regression across all cities/states, for multiple independent variables?**

Right now I have my program configured to run a linear OLS regression for two states or two cities for one independent variable at a time:

```
one = df1[col]
two = df2[[col,'const']].join(df3[col])
est = sm.OLS(one, two, missing='drop').fit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way for unbalanced panel data like this is to stack the time series for each cross-sectional unit and create dummy variables for the fixed effects.

Creating fixed effects for cross-sectional units (i.e. unit specific intercept), requires a categorical variable with the labels or ID of the states and cities. Then, the formula interface and patsy can create the required dummy variables using `C(id)`.

Then OLS can be used to estimate the FE model. The fit method has a cov_type option to use either panel or cluster robust standard errors to correct those for cross-sectional or within correlation.

Comment: Thanks for the response! The `"cov_type='nonrobust'` parameter in the fit() method is really helpful. The categorical variable for location I never would have thought to use. When complete, I will post updated designs of dataframes and the OLS methods used for the FE model.